# What is the correct order of watching of the Ghost In The Shell series?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell

In this post, *GITS* stands for Ghost in the shell and *SAC* stands for stand alone complex

**I've collected:**

- GITS arise quadrolgy
- GITS SAC 1st gig
- GITS SAC 1st gig solid state society
- GITS SAC 2nd gig
- GITS SAC 2nd gig individual eleven
- GITS 2 innocence
- GITS 2.0
- GITS the laughing man

**My queries are:**

- Except for GITS 1995, am I missing anything ?
- What is the correct order of watching?

Comment: Thank you, i had searched with the word chronology so didn't get it.